# jQuery UI datepicker: How to color sundays red?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

i need sundays to highlight in red.

I know that there is a class called  `ui-datepicker-week-end`.

My problem is, that the other classes (`ui-widget-content` and `ui-state-default`) overwrite the red color of `ui-datepicker-week-end`, even if set `!important`.

The only thing that is colored are the weekend days in the headline of the calendar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can style the anchors that are descendants of the `.ui-datepicker-week-end` elements, and set their `background-image` property to `none` when adding the background color. This gives good results without you having to use `!important`:

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end a {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**EDIT:** If you want to set the `color` property instead of `background-color`, you will indeed have to use `!important`:

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end a {
    color: red !important;
}
```

You can see the results in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eB9wm/).

Comment: thanks for your answer. But it is still overwritten. Please have a look at the screenshot of F12 developer tools: http://img0.www.suckmypic.net/img/g/X/rwFhrsfy/jquery-ui-calendar.png

Comment: Apologies, I thought you wanted to set `background-color` instead of `color`. However, `!important` works in my tests when used with `color`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Easy way

sunday color red this way

```
.datepicker table tr td:first-child {
color: red
}
```

monday color red this way

```
.datepicker table tr td:first-child +td {
color: red
}
```

thuesday color red this way

```
.datepicker table tr td:first-child + td + td {
color: red
}
```