# JQuery UI Datepicker Change Style for a Day

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm writing a simple script.

I read from a database non-working days, and I'd like to change the background/font color for these days. When I click a day, I toggle it background/font color.

**With non-working days, I'm not saying weekends, but mid-week days that are non-working, because of *national holidays*.**

How could I modify specific days in datepicker? Is this possible? May I design and code a custom calendar?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery UI datepicker: How to color sundays red?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294167/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-to-color-sundays-red)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked before, I think this (along with the fiddle) answers your question:

[jQuery UI datepicker: How to color sundays red?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10294167/jquery-ui-datepicker-how-to-color-sundays-red)

Datepicker has a `.ui-datepicker-week-end` element that you can use to change the background/font accordingly. An example given in the above is:

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end a {
    background-image: none;
    background-color: red;
}
```

If you want to set the color property instead of background-color, you will indeed have to use !important:

```
.ui-datepicker-week-end a {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Adding answer specifically for changing bank holiday dates for future reference. This is a nice step by step guide.

http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html

Comment: It's mid-week non-working days, like a wednesday that's a national holiday. I'd like to highlight these.

Comment: Something like this would work: http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html